# Did the prisoners in the pit know who Bruce Wayne was?

Tags: the-dark-knight-rises

During the whole imprisonment of Bruce Wayne in *The Dark Knight Rises*, did the prisoners know who he was, specifically that he was the Batman? I think they only knew him to be a friend of Bane.

Did they have any idea that Batman and Bruce Wayne were the same person?

Comment: I can't see what difference that would make, since the prison was now being run by Bane and he had given express order to keep Bruce alive till the bomb goes off.

Answer (score 10):

I don't remember any of the prisoner making any comment about Bruce Wayne while he is kept captive in the pit. Therefore, I would think that nobody knows who he is. After all, they are prisoners with few information coming from the outside world. Furthermore, their prison is in a country far away from where Bruce Wayne's activities are famous.

When he escapes, the prisoners cheer up not for who he is, but for what he has done : beaten the pit and showed all the prisoners that it was possible to escape, thus giving them great hope.

Comment: In the end he didn't just give them hope, but freed them, by lowering a rope down there once he escaped. Otherwise correct answer.

Comment: I don't remember lowering a rope.

Answer (score 1):

They almost certainly didn't know that he was the Batman (nor did they know that some bat-dressing hero even existed).

However, there is this conversation:

> **Bruce:** You told me a child did it.
>   **The prisoner:** But no ordinary child. A child born in hell. Forged from suffering. Hardened by pain. Not a man from privilege.

So, the prisoner knows that Bruce comes "from privilege". They already know that Bane has a special interest in Bruce, and that he's from Gotham (given his interest in the events there and his references to "my city").

It is not clear if they know his name, but I don't see how would that add any info to what they already knew, since -- being where they were -- it is not likely that they've ever heard of Gotham, let alone Bruce Wayne, before he was put in the pit.